# MongoDB responds slowly during the WiredTiger Checkpoint writing process

Tags: mongodb, checkpoint, wiredtiger

We have 3 instances of MongoDB `3.2.12` configured as a replica set. Journaling is enabled, the storage engine is WiredTiger.

Most of the time our application produces a very low load on the database server and it works well, but rarely we launch a background maintenance causing x10...x100 load increase, mostly due to `insert` operations: ~10000 inserts/sec.

Today during the maintenance we noticed that the response time of our application increased every 1 minute for a short time.
[image: app response time metric]

We suspected that it's related to the MongoDB server and found the following facts:

`mongostat` output example:

```
insert query update delete getmore command % dirty % used flushes vsize   res qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn set repl           time
   891   936    235     14     388  2620|0     4.6   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0   1|0 2.02m  2.38m  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:49+03:00
  1098   861      3     12     107   452|0     4.6   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0   1|1 1.07m  5.39m  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:50+03:00
 14602   725     11     14     259   727|0     4.7   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0   0|0 7.57m  8.44m  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:51+03:00
     4   527    260      1      23   100|0     4.7   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0   0|0  383k  3.60m  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:52+03:00
  8698   121    671     11     186   585|0     4.8   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0   2|0 5.61m  6.30m  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:53+03:00
  5539   645     21      9     199   623|0     4.9   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0   1|0 5.19m  5.77m  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:54+03:00
  2599   602     14      9      99   370|0     4.9   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0   1|0 1.48m  2.37m  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:55+03:00
  3507   485     22      3     139   415|0     4.9   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0   0|0 4.90m  5.33m  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:56+03:00

  3627   369   4019      9     133   415|0     4.3   80.0       1 33.8G 26.7G   0|0   4|3 4.59m  4.18m  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:57+03:00

     3    17     20      1      11    63|0     2.9   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0 13|12 29.8k  56.3k  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:58+03:00
     5    24      4      1      18    88|0     2.1   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0 18|16 39.1k   270k  208 rs0  PRI 14:55:59+03:00
     2     9      2      3       9    54|0     0.5   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0 22|20 20.2k  88.9k  208 rs0  PRI 14:56:00+03:00
     2    47     *0      3       2    21|0     0.3   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|0 24|23 18.0k  39.6k  208 rs0  PRI 14:56:01+03:00
 26635   991   5475     35     410  1189|0     0.8   80.0       0 33.8G 26.7G   0|1   2|0 16.4m  21.0m  207 rs0  PRI 14:56:02+03:00
```

- Moments, when the application is slow, perfectly match with moments when `mongstat` reports `flushes = 1`.
- MongoDB handles a very low number of requests in the next 4 seconds after this event.
- The `transaction checkpoint most recent time (msecs)` value from the `serverStatus` is also equal to ~4000 msec.

We launched `iostat -x -d 1` and found the following pattern:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              36.00   311.00   33.00   61.00   276.00  1384.00    35.32     0.04    0.39    0.36    0.41   0.34   3.20
sdb              60.00   311.00   21.00   61.00   324.00  1384.00    41.66     0.03    0.38    0.38    0.38   0.34   2.80
sdc              36.00   311.00   33.00   63.00   276.00  1392.00    34.75     0.04    0.43    0.33    0.48   0.38   3.60
sdd              57.00   311.00   20.00   63.00   308.00  1392.00    40.96     0.04    0.46    0.30    0.51   0.42   3.50
md126             0.00     0.00  296.00  695.00  1184.00  2776.00     7.99     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    7.00   21.00    28.00    36.00     4.57     0.01    0.43    0.29    0.48   0.32   0.90
sdb               0.00     0.00    4.00   21.00    16.00    36.00     4.16     0.01    0.40    0.25    0.43   0.28   0.70
sdc               0.00     0.00    6.00   21.00    24.00    36.00     4.44     0.01    0.26    0.33    0.24   0.19   0.50
sdd               0.00     0.00    4.00   21.00    16.00    36.00     4.16     0.01    0.24    0.25    0.24   0.16   0.40
md126             0.00     0.00   21.00   21.00    84.00    72.00     7.43     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    4.00     0.00     8.00     4.00     0.00    0.50    0.00    0.50   0.50   0.20
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    4.00     0.00     8.00     4.00     0.00    0.50    0.00    0.50   0.50   0.20
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    2.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    2.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md126             0.00     0.00    0.00    4.00     0.00     8.00     4.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00 17275.00    1.00 2824.00     4.00 79688.00    56.42    10.25    3.63    0.00    3.63   0.14  39.40
sdb               0.00 17275.00    1.00 2824.00     4.00 79688.00    56.42    10.65    3.77    0.00    3.77   0.14  39.60
sdc               0.00 17284.00    1.00 2799.00     4.00 79624.00    56.88    10.70    3.82    0.00    3.82   0.14  39.20
sdd               0.00 17284.00    1.00 2799.00     4.00 79624.00    56.88    11.40    4.07    0.00    4.07   0.15  40.70
md126             0.00     0.00    4.00 39867.00    16.00 159316.00     7.99     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              53.00 19426.00   64.00 4645.00   468.00 95132.00    40.60    18.43    3.91    0.31    3.96   0.11  52.80
sdb              28.00 19426.00   29.00 4645.00   228.00 95132.00    40.80    18.68    4.00    0.97    4.02   0.12  56.80
sdc              62.00 19463.00   61.00 4660.00   492.00 95340.00    40.60    24.42    5.17    1.00    5.23   0.12  57.00
sdd              18.00 19463.00   39.00 4660.00   228.00 95340.00    40.68    19.39    4.13    0.15    4.16   0.11  53.70
md126             0.00     0.00  357.00 47782.00  1428.00 190468.00     7.97     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              24.00  1261.00  275.00  127.00  1196.00  5348.00    32.56     0.10    0.26    0.11    0.59   0.24   9.80
sdb              55.00  1261.00   33.00  127.00   352.00  5348.00    71.25     0.09    0.54    0.30    0.61   0.52   8.30
sdc              61.00  1261.00  281.00  128.00  1368.00  5352.00    32.86     0.13    0.31    0.14    0.68   0.28  11.50
sdd              11.00  1261.00   38.00  128.00   196.00  5352.00    66.84     0.09    0.54    0.16    0.66   0.53   8.80
md126             0.00     0.00  775.00 2675.00  3100.00 10700.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              75.00  1161.00   59.00  165.00   536.00  5040.00    49.79     0.11    0.51    0.29    0.59   0.48  10.70
sdb               4.00  1161.00   37.00  165.00   164.00  5040.00    51.52     0.11    0.52    0.14    0.61   0.52  10.60
sdc              58.00  1151.00   58.00  165.00   464.00  5000.00    49.00     0.12    0.54    0.31    0.62   0.50  11.20
sdd              23.00  1151.00   33.00  165.00   224.00  5000.00    52.77     0.10    0.50    0.18    0.56   0.50   9.90
md126             0.00     0.00  347.00 2510.00  1388.00 10040.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Firstly, all IO activity metrics dropped to zeroes (that I can't explain at all), then we see a bunch of writes increasing `avgqu-sz` up to 20, and then all metrics returned to typical values.

So, I guess the performance degradation we experienced was related to the WiredTiger Checkpoint writing process which happens every 1 minute ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/)).

It looks that it takes a reasonable amount of time writing this amount of data, but why doesn't the MongoDB handle requests during this process? I thought it should happen in the background and shouldn't affect currently executing operations.

Comment: Looks like same what we had before moving to use only SSD based storages. Mongo requires high IOPS storage solutions.

Comment: @JJussi We use an SSD storage, but it's consumer grade

Comment: What O/S and filesystem are you using?

Comment: @Stennie CentOS, XFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have updated MongoDB and the issue disappeared. Most likely it was related to the bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-3362